# forgot to pull changes before merge

Tags: git, merge

I have a local branch `feature`, and to make future merge into `master` easier my intention was to "update" the `feature` branch by doing:

```
git pull --rebase
git checkout feature
git merge --no-ff master
git push origin feature
```

After resolving merge conflicts, but before `commit` and `push`, I realised that I had forgotten to run `git pull --rebase`, and thus, my local `master` was actually two commits behind the remote `master`.

Do I need to abort the merge, i.e. go back to the situation before running `merge`, and then do `git pull --rebase` followed by my previous merge attempt? Or can I do something to include `remote master` changes to my `local master`, as I would have pulled the changes before the current `merge`. Resolving the merge conflicts with those missing two commits would obviously be different from the current resolve.

Hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Why do you use `pull --rebase` by default? Is the upstream master always getting rebased? If you don't have local changes to `master` that actually require rebasing then there's no need to abort the merge, because the changes to master should apply cleanly to your local master, and so should then merge cleanly to your feature branch.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I don't have any local changes in `master` that require rebasing, so I can proceed with your suggestion of making two merges?

Comment: Yes, that should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to abort anything or restart if your local `master` is just two commits behind the remote `master` because you can just fetch and merge those two commits.

Just resolve your merge conflicts and commit the changes to the feature branch, then update master, and merge from master to `feature` again. This is exactly the same situation as if you *had* updated master first, but then someone had added some new commits to `origin/master` i.e. your local  master would be behind origin/master again. But that's not a problem, you just update your master and merge to feature again.

Or resolve conflicts and commit to the feature branch, then just `git fetch origin && git merge origin/master` to apply the latest upstream changes directly to the `feature` branch. (That will mean `feature` has commits that aren't in your `master` branch yet, but that's fine, you'll get them in master next time you update it).

N.B. if you enable [`rerere`](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html) then if you *did* decide to abort and restart the merge then you wouldn't need to re-resolve merge conflicts, because Git would remember the resolutions and reuse them.